# Is borel sigma field a subset of real number set R

Tags: probability-theory

Is it right to think that borel sigma field is a subset of real line which contains a large number of subsets of R, including R itself?Could any one suggest a pictorial representation like venn diagram to understand this?

Comment: One might have a large subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ which is not a Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Maybe you can think about (at least generated) $\sigma$-algebras as taking a couple of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and forcing the properties you want it to have: start including complements, countable unions, then after adding all that, you repeat, etc. This of course is only intuition because you would never end (not even in countable steps).

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra on a set is a subset of the **power set** of that set. So $$\mathcal B(\mathbb R) \subset 2^\mathbb R$$ where $$2^\mathbb R = \{S:S\subset \mathbb R\}. $$